# Truth table generator for an arbitrary function

Tags: r

**Summary**: This function generates a truth table for a boolean function of variable number of arguments. The name of the function passed and its arguments are deduced outside of the computable function scope. The returned value is a logical matrix with columns corresponding to function arguments and result.

```
library(R.utils)
library(stringr)

truthTable <- function(func, valuesOnly = F) {
  numArguments <- length(formals(func))
  if(valuesOnly) {
    values <- vector(length = 2^numArguments)
    for (i in 1:(2^numArguments)) {
      arguments <- rev(as.logical(intToBits(i-1)))[-(1:(32-numArguments))]
      values[i] <- do.call(func, as.list(arguments))
    }
    return(values)
  }
  result <- matrix(nrow = 2^numArguments, ncol = numArguments + 1)
  colnames(result) <- c(names(formals(func)), as.character(substitute(func)))
  for (i in 1:(2^numArguments)) {
    arguments <- rev(as.logical(intToBits(i-1)))[-(1:(32-numArguments))]
    result[i, ] <- c(arguments, do.call(func, as.list(arguments)))
  }
  return(result)
}
```

**Example**:

```
majority <- function(a, b, c) {
  return ((a & b) | (b & c) | (a & c))
}

truthTable(majority)
```

**Result**:

```
         a     b     c majority
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE    FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE    FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE    FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE     TRUE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE    FALSE
[6,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE     TRUE
[7,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE     TRUE
[8,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE     TRUE
```

**Possible improvements**:

- Faster conversion of numeric iterator to logical vector
- Usage of `apply` instead of iterative computation

What could be improved?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

The main flaw that can be observed in your function is the presence of **code duplication**: expressions such as `2^numArguments` and `arguments <- rev(as.logical(intToBits(i-1)))[-(1:(32-numArguments))]` appear multiple times. Code duplication is generally bad, you could refactor so that each of them appears only one time.

Other little things:

- `R.utils` and `stringr` are loaded but never used.
- It's better to use `FALSE` instead of `F`.

Here is an alternative solution using `expand.grid`:

```
truthTable2 <- function(func, valuesOnly = FALSE) {
  args <- formals(func)
  L <- setNames(rep(list(c(TRUE, FALSE)), length(args)), names(args))
  df <- expand.grid(L)
  result <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) do.call(func, lapply(df, `[`, i)))
  # or result <- do.call(func, df) if func is vectorized
  if (valuesOnly) {
    unname(result)
  } else {
    df[[substitute(func)]] <- result
    as.matrix(df)
  }
}

truthTable(majority)
#          a     b     c majority
# [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE     TRUE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE     TRUE
# [3,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE     TRUE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE    FALSE
# [5,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE     TRUE
# [6,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE    FALSE
# [7,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE    FALSE
# [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE    FALSE
```

---

**Benchmark:**

```
bench::mark(
  truthTable(majority),
  truthTable2(majority),
  check = FALSE
)
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
# expression                min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time 
# <bch:expr>            <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <lis>
# 1 truthTable(majority)   89.5us  97.4us     9634.    1.44KB     6.22  4650     3      483ms <lgl[~ <df[,~ <bch~
# 2 truthTable2(majority) 189.6us 204.7us     4292.        0B     4.07  2110     2      492ms <lgl[~ <df[,~ <bch~
# # ... with 1 more variable: gc <list>


bigf <- function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q) TRUE

bench::mark(
  truthTable(bigf),
  truthTable2(bigf),
  check = FALSE
)
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#   expression             min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result               memory            time    gc           
#   <bch:expr>        <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>               <list>            <list>  <list>       
# 1 truthTable(bigf)     2.13s    2.13s     0.469      64MB     5.63     1    12      2.13s <lgl[,18] [131,072 ~ <df[,3] [262,351~ <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x~
# 2 truthTable2(bigf)    2.43s    2.43s     0.412    76.5MB     5.77     1    14      2.43s <lgl[,18] [131,072 ~ <df[,3] [262,218~ <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x~
# Warning message:
# Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
```

Comment: Indeed, code duplication should be avoided, and unused packager will be deleted (although may return as i find a faster way to convert the iterator from numeric to logical vector). Other than that, the suggested function (for illustrative purposed I will call it ```truthTable2``` is slower in my tests on a function with many (17, to be specific) arguments. It just returns ```TRUE``` all the time, so this is more of a test to see how fast the function handles the truth table generation. While ```truthTable``` takes 3 seconds to compute, the ```truthtable2``` takes 28.

Comment: But I appreciate the clarity of the code and will try to implement the best practices to improve the function performance. But R is not all about performance, and I might need to code this function in C++ to gain a significant boost, might do it later

Comment: Assuming `func` is vectorized, like it is the case with your `majority`,  replacing the `sapply` with a single call `result <- do.call(func, df)` should give it a good boost.

Comment: @F.Rosty You're right, it was really slow! The main bottleneck was the `split` on dataframe rows, I've replaced it and now it's much faster. And as flodel said you can also use the fact that `func` is vectorized (if it is).